# Accordion effect on picture

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I want to apply an accordion effect with jQuery on a picture.

I use this syntax...

```
// jQuery
$(document).ready(function() 
{
$("dt.tooltip")
  .addClass("js")
  .hover(function()
  {
     $(this).toggleClass("active").next().toggle();
  }
  )
  .next().hide();
}
);
  // Html
  <dt class="tooltip">Mail <img src="../pictures/help.png" title="" alt="" /></dt>
  <dd><!-- Text --></dd>
```

On hover, dd content displays. Everything is ok!

But I want to apply accordion effect only with hover picture. I tried with...

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
$(".tooltip")
  .addClass("js")
  .hover(function()
  {
     $(this).toggleClass("active").next().toggle();
  }
  )
  .next().hide();
}
);
  // Html
  <dt">Mail <span class="tooltip"><img src="../pictures/help.png" title="" alt="" /></span></dt>
  <dd><!-- Text --></dd>
```

But it doesn't work!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks à lot.

Vincent

Comment: Can we have the CSS as well please? You are referencing classes called `js` and `active` but without them, it might be difficult to re-create your problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Could you try to replicate the problem on http://jsfiddle.net/, and post a link so we can easily reproduce it?

Answer (score 2):

Set your image to `display:none;` and add the line

```
 $('dt.tooltip img').toggleClass("active").toggle();
```

so your final code looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("dt.tooltip")
  .addClass("js")
  .hover(function()
  {
     $(this).toggleClass("active").next().toggle();
      $('dt.tooltip img').toggleClass("active").toggle();
  }
  )
  .next().hide();
}
);
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/fLtF3/

Comment: +1 for the car image... would be nice if you could add the relevant part to your answer, in case something happens to jsfiddle :)